# ACS712 cutting out

Tags: current, integrated-circuit, power-electronics, current-measurement, measurement

**Update:** I replaced the IC on the ACS board with a new one from element14 and pleased to say all works as expected, putting this one down to counterfeit IC, thanks everyone

---

I'm using an ACS712 based current sensor board

(Exact here: http://tinkersphere.com/sensors/1244-hall-effect-current-sensor-breakout-acs712.html)

For testing purposes I have connected Vcc and GND to a bench power supply, OUT and Gnd to a general purpose oscilloscope and connected the terminal current sensing inputs in series to a 12V(rms) AC transformer powering a 12 Ohm load providing 1amp of current through the board.

However after switching the 12V ac supply a few the board cuts out producing a flat 2.5V DC output.

Initially I thought this could be thermal shut down however the chip is barely over room temp

Behaviour seems to be like the board is cutting out as the noise normally present on the output pin with no input is supressed.

All images in single imgur post

Images:

[Scope output images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foxP9.jpg)

Comment: I would suggest measuring the current with a multimeter or something comparable to proof that there is really current. Perhaps your light switch dies because of the inductive load and has contact problems. Or there is a connection problem.

Comment: Its not the switch cutting out, the output of the current sense board stays fixed at 2.5 volts after power cycling. Checked with multi-meter and when the ACS board cuts out there is still 1amp (rms) ac current through the board

Comment: There is absolutely no reason why that should be happening. The only thing I can think of is an intermittent short on the current sense path that bypasses the sensor. If the sensor is outputting 2.5V, then VCC is obviously present. All the IC really needs is VCC. There is no enable pin or anything, and it is very robust against over-current. If all else fails, get a new sensor and see if the problem persists.

Comment: I have about 4 identical boards and I've tried each of them with the same issue persisting. It seems as if its some sort of protection circuitry in the chip and fast switching of the AC causes the output to clamp at that 2.5V. The application I'm using them for is to sense current on a 24V AC pump which involved the pump switching, hence why this is an issue. Perhaps its a Chinese clone of the chip. I will take closer photos of the chip tomorrow and see if I can find the exact variant or if anyone can tell if its a clone

Comment: The current sense path on the ACS chips is just a couple of mOhms, and the overload current is like 50X the max sense current. It is very strange. It doesn't even have a mode of operation like that, where the output is suppressed. You could order a real one from a supplier like mouser or digikey and replace the IC on your board.

Comment: The one other thing that could maybe cause this is if the load on the analog output pin of the ACS is super high, and it is unable to drive it. Like if you connected it to a 2.5V power supply, or if there were a really large capacitor on the analog ouput. I know, probably neither of these would apply to you, but just throwing it out there.

Comment: What makes you think that the device was designed to sense AC current?  I recommend doing the same tests but use 12V DC, instead.  That might solve your problem.

Comment: I am familiar with the ACS712. It is bipolar, and can measure AC or DC currents. Datasheet for the ACS712 claims 80kHz BW.

Comment: Yes it works with 12V DC switching, just the AC im having issues with.

Comment: Replaced the IC on the ACS board with a new one from element14 and pleased to say all works as expected, putting this one down to counterfeit IC, thanks everyone

Comment: mkeith if you want to add your comment about the replacement IC as an answer I can accept it, cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, time constraints meant I was unable to investigate further, however, I ordered some ACS712 chips from a different supplier and fitted them to the module. After doing that the modules worked fine meaning it must have been manufacturing defective chips.